# How to use PDO to issue a query to a database and return the results?

Tags: php, pdo

So I am trying to use PDO to query a database and return the results. I have been following along with the php manual and looking on this site but I'm not seeing a solution to my problem. Basically when I run the code below I get no results, nothing; just a blank page. I have php set to show me errors but none are returned. Here is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
//this is where you put the login information:
$username = "my.user.name";
$password = "my.password";
$hostname = "localhost";

//this connects to the database:
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=first_base', $username, $password);

//this selects the data from the table(s)
function getResults($stuff) {
$stmt = "SELECT name, date, type, location FROM information ORDER BY name";
foreach($stuff->query($stmt) as $row) {
  print $row['name'];
    print $row['date'];
    print $row['type'];
    print $row['location'];


}
}
 getResults($stuff)

?>
```

Comment: Use the answer found here.

http://stackoverflow.com/q/13165627/1507210

Comment: Any chance you are actually *calling*  getResults()?

Comment: wow whoops. yeah I call on the function - I just left it out when I copied this over. I'll fix it via edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to your PDO connection `$dbh` instead of `$stuff` when calling the function -

```
getResults($dbh)
```

Comment: Now they'll tell you 'wow whoops variable is all right'. That's what a call *not a real* question

Comment: that fixed it. the php manual doesn't say that is necessary or to even do that. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Take a look at [Function arguments - http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) and [Variable scope - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) from the php docs to understand why this is neccessary